# Detect data changes in postgresql

Tags: java, database, postgresql, liquibase

Is there any way to detect data changes on postgresql wihtout touching the database structure (creating :procedures ,triggers ...).

We thought about a listener that keep listening to log file and parse it in order to know if there are a data change (insert / delete / modification).

I am not sure if the log parsing is efficient enough for such a deal.

Comment: For what kind of deal? What are you trying to do? Why can't you change the db? Why must you know when the data changes? Can't you use a different mechanism (such as having the party that changes the database notify you that it has done something)?

Comment: Logical replication maybe? https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/replication.html

Comment: @Kayaman 
I have two components(A,B), A uses the real db but B uses a partial cache of the db. 
This is the reason behind the data change management ,making the cache synchronized with the original db each time there are a data change.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I will have a look on this

Comment: Yeah, don't roll your own solutions for things like this.

Comment: @Kayaman any existing solutions that could help ? :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name could you please add that as answer

Answer (score 1):

You should tell your target and why you can not change the structure for a better help.

But maybe that could help https://dzone.com/articles/audit-log-database-changes-in-postgresql